# Convert strings containing date ranges to dates and find time difference in R

Tags: string, r, date, substring

I have a column of data:

```
dates  <- c("20140106_20140131", "20140106_20140331", "20140201_20140210", 
            "20140201_20140228", "20140211_20140220", "20140221_20140228",
            "20140301_20140310", "20140301_20140331")
```

I want R to know these variables are "date to date" format

**Questions**

1. How to write R code to convert to date format? e.g. the first variable: "01/06/2014 to 01/31/2014".
2. How to compute the date duration?

Comment: Check out the `lubridate` package

Comment: Thanks! i am reading this package manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# vector of your date ranges
dates <- c("20140106_20140131", "20140106_20140331", "20140201_20140210", 
       "20140201_20140228", "20140211_20140220", "20140221_20140228", 
       "20140301_20140310", "20140301_20140331")

library('stringr')
library('lubridate')
```

First create a data frame with two columns of dates.

```
date_frame <- data.frame(str_split_fixed(dates, "_", 2))
```

Then convert the dates from strings using `lubridate`'s `ymd()` function.

```
date_frame$X1 <- ymd(date_frame$X1)
date_frame$X2 <- ymd(date_frame$X2)
```

Create a new column of time differences.

```
transform(date_frame, diff = X2 - X1)
          X1         X2    diff
1 2014-01-06 2014-01-31 25 days
2 2014-01-06 2014-03-31 84 days
3 2014-02-01 2014-02-10  9 days
4 2014-02-01 2014-02-28 27 days
5 2014-02-11 2014-02-20  9 days
6 2014-02-21 2014-02-28  7 days
7 2014-03-01 2014-03-10  9 days
8 2014-03-01 2014-03-31 30 days
```